# SQLAlchemy search using .contains() is too sensitive

Tags: python, search, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that has a search bar where users can search a database for users. This is the code:

```
users = []
for keyword in query.split():
  result = db.session.query(Users).filter(User.name.contains(keyword)).all()
  for user in result:
    users.append(user.name)
```

Using the example above, if I was to search for 'a' then every user with the letter 'a' in their name will appear. How can I search the User table so that instead of searching by letter, it would search by word? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression with SQLAlchemy:

```
result = db.session.query(Users).filter(User.name.op('regexp')(r'\b{}\b'.format(keyword))).all()
```

> \b
>   Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string, so the precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags. For example, r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'. Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I added your suggestion and I searched for a `User.name` 'John' with a query of 'John' and it did not find it.

Comment: Maybe case sensitive is matter?

Comment: Hm the cases are not the issue

Answer (score 0):

[Eugene Soldatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031981/eugene-soldatov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33221006/5320906) is broadly correct: to search for a word within a string we can use a regular expression comprised of your search term wrapped in word boundary markers. However we must consider that the implementation of regular expressions may differ depending on the RDBMS that is being queried.

Say we want to find rows containing the word "apple", the regular expression to use would be:

- SQLite<sup>1</sup>: `'\\bapple\\b'`
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)<sup>2</sup> / [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regular-expressions-overview/#word-boundaries)<sup>3</sup>: [[:<:]]apple[[:>:]]'`or`'`'\\bapple\\b'`
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES): `'\\mapple\\M'`

As well as using varying syntaxes for regular expressions, RDBMS differ in the SQL syntax used to match a regular expression. SQLAlchemy provides a [regexp_match](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.regexp_match) method which abstracts these differences away since v1.4:

```py
term = 'apple'
select(Fruit.name).where(Fruit.name.regexp_match(fr'\b{term}\b'))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> SQLite doesn't implement regular expressions, but provides a hook which SQLAlchemy uses to use Python's regex engine.

<sup>2</sup> Before  v8.0.4 used an implementation that used the first boundary markers; v8.0.4 and later uses `\b`.

<sup>3</sup> Before v10.0.5 MariaDB used a POSIX-compliant implementation that used the first boundary markers. v10.0.5 use a PCRE implementation that supports `\b`.